# Android Player Error (-38,0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i made a stream program to play an ad + audio + ad. i play first ad fine , then i switch to the audio which fine then i fail at playing the last ad and i get Error(38,0). i checked that i have set data source,onPrepareListener and i tried every thing i can found so far but still getting this error on android 4.1.1 
I get error after my method MPStarting , i do not even reach the onPrepared method only for final ad.if there is any info u need more plz let me know thanks.
here is the part of code which is related

```
MPStarting(Track)
{    try
{   
    if (_playlist !=null && _playlist.GetCurrent() != null)
    {                   
        Episode ep = (Episode) _playlist.GetCurrent();
        _player = new MediaPlayer();
        AdsInfo startAd = ep.getAdWithType(PlayTime.start_ad);
        AdsInfo endAd = ep.getAdWithType(PlayTime.end_ad);
        if(currAudio == null && startAd != null)
            currAudio = startAd;
        else if(currAudio == startAd )
            currAudio = ep;
        else if (currAudio instanceof Episode && endAd != null)
            currAudio = ep.getAdWithType(PlayTime.end_ad);
    }
    if(_player != null)
    {
        _player.setDataSource(dataSource);
        _player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        _player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        _player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        _player.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        _player.setOnErrorListener(this);           
        _player.prepareAsync();
    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Log.i("mpcPlayer","MPStarting "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } 

}
}
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
//here i check on current playing
//i always stop player if it is playing ,reset,release and make player = null
// then i call MPStarting and i send the current audio then return
}
```

Comment: are you streaming the Ad3

Comment: streaming mp3 track , some times i play it from SDcard

Comment: playing from SDcard should not be an issue. We generally get this error when we play from the streaming server, when the mediaplayer timeout for buffering is expired. If possible always try to play from sdcard.

Comment: the app gives chance to download\stream so can not all the time ...I think i found the problem ,i was calling sometimes getCurrentPosition() it seems player was not ready at that time.i guess this error is about calling a method sometimes while player not in right state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found my problem ,i was calling sometimes getCurrentPosition() it seems player was not ready at that time.i guess this error is about calling a method sometimes while player not in right state.